# "neuralnet","nn": ANN model error

Tags: r, neural-network

I am using the bank-data set available on the UCI machine learning repository in order to try and construct an ANN in R.

The structure of the data is like so:

```
> head(bank_data)
             age       job marital   education default housing loan   contact month day_of_week       duration      campaign        pdays
1  1.53301567694 housemaid married    basic.4y      no      no   no telephone   may         mon  0.01047129616 -0.5659151042 0.1954115279
2  1.62897345569  services married high.school unknown      no   no telephone   may         mon -0.42149539806 -0.5659151042 0.1954115279
3 -0.29018211937  services married high.school      no     yes   no telephone   may         mon -0.12451829578 -0.5659151042 0.1954115279
4 -0.00230878311    admin. married    basic.6y      no      no   no telephone   may         mon -0.41378170709 -0.5659151042 0.1954115279
5  1.53301567694  services married high.school      no      no  yes telephone   may         mon  0.18788618843 -0.5659151042 0.1954115279
6  0.47748011065  services married    basic.9y unknown      no   no telephone   may         mon -0.23250996934 -0.5659151042 0.1954115279
       previous    poutcome emp.var.rate cons.price.idx cons.conf.idx    euribor3m  nr.employed targetVar
1 -0.3494900415 nonexistent 0.6480843991    0.722713697  0.8864358006 0.7124512301 0.3316758805        no
2 -0.3494900415 nonexistent 0.6480843991    0.722713697  0.8864358006 0.7124512301 0.3316758805        no
3 -0.3494900415 nonexistent 0.6480843991    0.722713697  0.8864358006 0.7124512301 0.3316758805        no
4 -0.3494900415 nonexistent 0.6480843991    0.722713697  0.8864358006 0.7124512301 0.3316758805        no
5 -0.3494900415 nonexistent 0.6480843991    0.722713697  0.8864358006 0.7124512301 0.3316758805        no
6 -0.3494900415 nonexistent 0.6480843991    0.722713697  0.8864358006 0.7124512301 0.3316758805        no
```

Here is the data and libraries I am using:

```
library(dplyr)
library(class)
library(neuralnet)
library(nnet)
library(lubridate)

bank_data <- read.csv("Data/bank-additional-full.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")

# Manually create "target var"
bank_data$targetVar <- bank_data$y
bank_data <- select(bank_data, -y)

# Normalize the data
bank_num_vars <- sapply(bank_data, is.numeric)
bank_data[bank_num_vars] <- lapply(bank_data[bank_num_vars], scale)

#SplitData
trainObs <- sample(nrow(bank_data), .6 * nrow(bank_data), replace = FALSE)
valObs <- sample(nrow(bank_data), .2 * nrow(bank_data), replace = FALSE)
testObs <- sample(nrow(bank_data), .2 * nrow(bank_data), replace = FALSE)

# Create the training/va/test datasets
trainDS <- bank_data[trainObs,]
valDS <- bank_data[valObs,]
testDS <- bank_data[testObs,]
# One-hot encoding the variables
trainDS <- cbind(select(trainDS, -targetVar), class.ind(as.factor(trainDS$targetVar)))
valDS <- cbind(select(valDS, -targetVar), class.ind(as.factor(valDS$targetVar)))
testDS <- cbind(select(testDS, -targetVar), class.ind(as.factor(testDS$targetVar)))

n_train <- names(trainDS)
n_val <- names(valDS)
n_test <- names(testDS)

# Create the formula
f <- as.formula(paste("no + yes ~", paste(n_train[!n_train %in% c("no", "yes")], collapse = " + ")))
f_val <- as.formula(paste("no + yes ~", paste(n_val[!n_val %in% c("no","yes")], collapse = " + ")))
f_test <- as.formula(paste("no + yes ~", paste(n_test[!n_test %in% c("no","yes")], collapse = " + ")))

# Run the ANN
nn <- neuralnet(f, data = trainDS, hidden = c(13, 10, 3), act.fct = "logistic", linear.output = FALSE, lifesign = "minimal")
```

When I try to run this code, it throws an error:

> > nn <- neuralnet(f, data = trainDS, hidden = c(13, 10, 3), act.fct = "logistic", linear.output = FALSE, lifesign = "minimal") hidden: 13,
> >     10, 3    thresh: 0.01    rep: 1/1    steps:  Error in neurons[[i]] %*%
> >     weights[[i]] :    requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your way of splitting the data into training/testing seems unorthodox.  A split should literally split the data (every observation is used and is only used in a single set).

Comment: Please provide output of `str(trainDS)`.  That error suggests your data is not in a valid format.